# How to angular route for sub modules?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a `dashboard` module in my angular application. And my `app.module.ts` is like following.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DashboardModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And `app-routing.module.ts` is

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And `dashboard.route.ts` is

```
const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRouteModuel {}
```

But the applciaiton is routing to `PageNotFoundComponent` always.

Comment: Do you want to lazy load your module, or have one app bundle?

Comment: please try to change `redirectTo: '/dashboard'` to `redirectTo: 'dashboard'`, remove `/`

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan removed / but did not work.

Comment: are you imported your `DashboardRouteModuel ` into `DashboardModule `?

Answer (score 1):

Your routing concepts are not correct. Simply put, you have to do:

- on the app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: 'path/to/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

- and on the dashboard-route.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRouteModule {}
```

- don't forget you must have a dashboard.module.ts with the class name "DashboardModule" where you import the dashboard-rote.module.ts, in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the module routing on lazy loading. You can change:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

by

```
{
    path: '',
    loadChildren:
        '../../dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
}
```

Docs:
[Lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Change order of imports AppRoutingModule and DashboardModule like following.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    DashboardModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```